# php eliminate blank option lines in for loop echo

Tags: php, html, arrays, multidimensional-array, echo

I have a strange thing happening and I don't know why.  I have a multidimensional array that looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( 
              [title] => I'm a title
              [desc] => Value1*Value2*Option1*Option2*Option3*Value3))
```

When I output it into a table everything works perfectly except the option values.  I get a blank option after each value.  Why is that?  Here's what I have:

```
for ($j=0; $j<count($_SESSION[$ses]); $j++){
    echo '<tr><td>'.$_SESSION[$ses][$j]['title'].'</td>';
    $desc = explode("*", $_SESSION[$ses][$j]['desc']);
    echo '<td>$'.$desc[0].'</td><td>'.$desc[1].'</td><td><select>';
for ($i=2; $i<count($desc)-1; $i++){
    echo '<option>'.$desc[$i].'<option>';
}
    echo '</select></td>
}
```

I couldn't find a solution anywhere.  Any advice?  It's not the end of the world but it just doesn't look ideal.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Second `'<option>'` tag needs to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to close the `option` tag

This should do it.

```
for ($j=0; $j<count($_SESSION[$ses]); $j++){
    echo '<tr><td>'.$_SESSION[$ses][$j]['title'].'</td>';
    $desc = explode("*", $_SESSION[$ses][$j]['desc']);
    echo '<td>$'.$desc[0].'</td><td>'.$desc[1].'</td><td><select>';
for ($i=2; $i<count($desc)-1; $i++){
    echo '<option>'.$desc[$i].'</option>'; /* This one you forgot */
}
    echo '</select></td>
}
```

Comment: Staring at code all day...making stupid mistakes.  Thanks!

Comment: We all know the feeling ;) Gl.